# Compiling libpcap results Undefined reference to `pcap_parse'

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, libpcap

Sorry if I am wrong but I am trying to compile the libpcap for Android with NDK. Finally, I get this error:

in grammar.y we can see :

```
#ifndef YYBISON
int yyparse(void);

int
pcap_parse()
{
   return (yyparse());
}
#endif
```

=> pcap_parse is defined if YYBISON is not defined

BUT in gencode.c, we have (line 342)

```
lex_init(buf ? buf : "");
init_linktype(pcap_datalink(p));
(void)pcap_parse();
```

AND in gencode.h (line 299)

```
struct bpf_insn *icode_to_fcode(struct block *, int *);
int pcap_parse(void);
void lex_init(char *);
void lex_cleanup(void);
```

=> pcap_parse if used without any test case !!
Result is a libpcap wrong if YYBISON is defined
(undedefined function pcap_parse)

Where is my error?

Comment: What are the contents of the `config.log` file in the source directory in which you're building libpcap?  If you have Bison, the Makefile should be generating `grammar.c` with `bison -y -p pcap_`, which should cause `grammar.c` to directly define `pcap_parse()`, so that the `pcap_parse()` wrapper isn't necessary.  Somehow, that's not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was really easy. I just do a `make distclean` at the sources. If it doesn't work try to a `git reset --hard` and it should be fixed.

Thanks everyone